# Radiator and coolant ports

Tags: mazda

I think I have a leak in my radiator because water came pouring out from under my car mazda 6s 2002. The only thing is when I opened my coolant cap it was still full. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you tell from the liquid on the ground if it was antifreeze? Any evidence of steam?  Any chance it was windshield solvent or from a/c condensation.

Comment: Did you check when the Engine was hot or after allowing it to cool for sometime ?

Comment: Did you check the radiator itself, or the overflow tank? If you lost coolant through a leak, the overflow would not be a good indicator of the level. You would need to check the pressurized system--after it's cooled off and no longer pressurized!

Answer (score 1):

Was the A/C running prior to this? It could be condensation from the A/C. Coolant tends to be pretty green and smelly so you'd have little trouble mistaking it for water.

The other option, as mentioned by mikes, is that you have a hole in your windshield cleaner bottle.

Comment: Coolant or windshield cleaner will have distinctive colors and smells: you might want to suggest those as well.

Comment: yeah, but windshield cleaner could be mistaken for water. sometimes it even *is* water.